# From which chapter should I start reading the manga "How a Realist Hero Rebuilt the Kingdom"?

Tags: genkoku

I have completed watching "How a Realist Hero Rebuilt the Kingdom", season 1. From which chapter should I start reading the manga to continue with the story?

Comment: I do not know the answer to your question, but you should know Season 1 is still airing.  It's second cour started three or four weeks ago, and Funimation aired episode 18 on 5 Feb 2022.